# 2 Dimensional Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
A [] [] > 1[] > 2[] > 3[null]
   |
B [] [] > 1[] > 2[null]
   |
C [] [] > 1[] > 2[] > 3[] > 4[] > 5[null]
   |
D[null][] > 2[] > 3[] > 4[null]
```

There are two Dimensional linked List, how can I use the single Linked list to build this data structure? A>B>C>D is Linked List and A node has 1>2>3 linked list.

```
public class Node 
public Object data;   
public Node next;
public Node down;
public Node (Object data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
    this.down = null;
}

public Node (Object data, Node next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

private Node head;
private Node tail;

public void addHead(Object item) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = tail = new ListNode(item);
        } else {
            head = new ListNode(item, head);
        }
    }

public void addTail(Object item) {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        head = tail = new Node(item);
    } else {
        tail.next = new Node(item);
        tail =  tail.next;
    }
}
```

how can I add each node in the linked list has an associated linked list.

Comment: By  " how can I use the single Linked list to build this data structure" do you mean that you want to eliminate the need of the pointer "down" and store all your elements into a Singly Linked List and figure out which node is child of whom to depict a 2D Linked List?

Comment: Yes, each node in the linked list has an associated linked list. A>B>C>D and A>1>2>3

Comment: why not use an associative array structure like LinkedHashMap <String, ArrayList <Integer>>?

Comment: because there are some requirement need to follow only can use the linked list to build this data structure :(

Comment: Be clear about the structure you must work with. It is the definition of Node that you have above (with `data`, `next` and `down` members) or is it something else (with only `data` and `next` members)?

Comment: @ddccdcd Do you have any distinguish between the parent node and the sub linked list? Because in this case, what you can do is add all elements in a single linked list and identify which data is which. For eg. if data of Node is 'B' then it'd indicate start of a new list and if for any element say '3' if next is not a number, it'd indicate end of a list.
OR
You can store count of children in parent node and use it to identify children nodes.

Comment: @Welbog I think in A,B,C,D have data, next and down. In the number 1,2,3,4 only have data and next

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida I update the data structure, I think the parent node have more one  pointer to find the sub linked list

Comment: You're overthinking it.  Create a single linked list class that is just a 1D linked list.  That's all you need-  a 2d linked list class is just a 1D linked list class where every item in it is a 1D linked list.

Comment: @ddccdcd The illustration you have shown above, do you want to implement that structure using linked list? I think I got you wrong. I thought you wanted to keep all elements in a single linked list without have to maintain a linked list for each parent element. Which one is it?

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida Yes, I want to implement that structure using linked list

Comment: @GabeSechan So, I need add new method for 2D linked list?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say parent nodes are `{A, B, C, D}` and child nodes are subsidiary node of each parent.

to insert parent node:

```
1. add node at the end / down of parent node link.
```

we can use following code to add parent node to end of the link.

```
static Node head, tail;
private static void addHeadNode(Object item) {
    if(head == null && tail == null) {
        head = new Node(item);
        tail = head;
    }else {
        /* add node at the end */
        tail.down = new Node(item);
        /* make tail points to at the end again */
        tail = tail.down;
    }
}
```

for example, if you have parent node list `{A,B,C,D}` and you want to add another parent node `k` then the above code add node `k` at the last position of parent node link.

```
|Before Adding Node K|                    |After Adding Node K|

     A                                           A
     |                                           |
     B                                           B
     |                                           |
     C                                           C
     |                                           |
     D                                           D
                                                 |
                                                 K
```

Now to add child node for particular parent, you can follow the below procedure:

```
1. Traverse the parent node
1.1. if node found add node at the end of this parent
1.2. if node not found, do nothing.
```

Code for above procedure should be:

```
private static void addOnHead(Object headNode, Object item) {
    Node temp = head;
    // traverse the parent node.
    while(temp != null && temp.data != headNode) {
        temp = temp.down;
    }
    /* if parent node found, add child node at the end of the parent */
    if(temp != null) {
        Node temp1 = temp;
        
        while(temp1.next != null) {
            temp1 = temp1.next;
        }
        temp1.next = new Node(item);
    }else {
        /* do nothing */
        System.out.println("no head node found!");
    }
}
```

Traversing Parent Nodes:

```
private static void traversingParentNodes() {
    Node temp = head;
    
    while(temp != null) {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp = temp.down;
    }
}
```

Traversing a Particular Child Node:

```
private static void traverseAChildNode(Object item) {
    Node temp = head;
    
    while(temp != null && temp.data != item) {
        //System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp = temp.down;
    }
    
    if(temp != null) {
        Node temp1 = temp.next;
        while(temp1 != null) {
            System.out.print(temp1.data+" ");
            temp1 = temp1.next;
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("head node not found!");
    }
}
```

Traversing entire list:

```
  private static void traverse2DLinkedList(Object item) {
    Node parent = head;
    while(parent != null) {
        Node child = parent.next;
        
        while(child != null) {
            System.out.print(child.data+" ");
            child = child.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
        parent = parent.down;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am much obliged to you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

**this way you won't be able to put the value in the correct nodes**

```
s.addToTail('A');
s.addToTail(1);
s.addToTail(2);
s.addToTail(3);
System.out.println(s);
```

**in this case you have to do something like that**

```
s.addToTail('A');
Node tail = s.tail;
tail.addToTail(1);
tail.addToTail(2);
tail.addToTail(3);
System.out.println(s);
```